# Critical event in PDLOGMSGS_LAST24HOURS

Tags: db2, monitoring, db2-luw

On Db2 v11.1 Enterprise on Linux I have checked "Critical Severity" problems using SQL:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP, MSG FROM SYSIBMADM.PDLOGMSGS_LAST24HOURS
WHERE MSGSEVERITY = 'C' ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY


TIMESTAMP                  MSG
-------------------------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2022-01-27-08.20.05.144296 ADM2017C  The Event Monitor "DB2DETAILDEADLOCK" has reached its file capacity.
                           Delete the files in the target directory
                           "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/NODE0000/SQL00001/MEMBER0000/db2event/db2detaildeadlock
                           " or move them to another directory.
```

The same error as in PDLOGMSGS_LAST24HOURS is also in db2di.nfy file:

```
2022-01-27-08.20.05.144296   Instance:XXXXX   Node:000
PID:13359(db2evmgi (DB2DETAILDEADLOCK) 0)   TID:3451905792   Appid:*LOCAL.DB2.220127072107
database monitor  sqmEvmonWriter::activate Probe:40   Database:XXXXXXX

ADM2017C  The Event Monitor "DB2DETAILDEADLOCK" has reached its file capacity.
Delete the files in the target directory
"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/NODE0000/SQL00001/MEMBER0000/db2event/db2detaildeadlock
" or move them to another directory.
```

but checking the db2diag.log file and I get LEVEL: Warning

```
2022-01-27-08.20.05.143966+060 I523427079E747        LEVEL: Warning
PID     : 13359                TID : 140646450980608 PROC : db2sysc 0
INSTANCE: XXXXXXXXXX           NODE : 000            DB   : XXXXXXX
APPHDL  : 0-35088              APPID: *LOCAL.DB2.220127072107
AUTHID  : XXXXXXX              HOSTNAME: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
EDUID   : 12790                EDUNAME: db2evmgi (DB2DETAILDEADLOCK) 0
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, database monitor, sqmEvmonWriter::activate, probe:40
MESSAGE : ADM2017C  The Event Monitor "DB2DETAILDEADLOCK" has reached its file
          capacity. Delete the files in the target directory
          "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/NODE0000/SQL00001/MEMBER0000/db2event/db2deta
          ildeadlock" or move them to another directory.
```

Why is there a Severity = Critical in PDLOGMSGS_LAST24HOURS and Level = Warning in db2diag.log

Regards

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question. Perhaps you should open a PMR? If you come up with an answer that way, please post it as an answer to your question. You won't get any points for doing so, but people can upvote your answer.

Comment: I investigated and like I understand it now, it is critical _nofitication_ because event monitor was turned off for some reason (this info is in db2di.nfy), but from the perspective of database (this info is in db2diag.log) it is just warning, because event monitor does not effect correct behavior of database.

Comment: That makes sense, I think you should make an answer out of it.